# GemGis: 12 Visualizing Geological Cross Sections with PyVista: No texture coordinates

Tags: pyvista

I have installed GEMGIS with version 1.1.3.
I use PYVISTA version Version: 0.39.1
I use GEMGIS with GEMPY in the version 2.3.1

All is running well.
But: When I follow the tutorial 12 Visualizing Geological Cross Sections with PyVista the following error appears when I try to add the mesh with textures to the PyVista - Plotter:

File "C:\Users\ga93sos\miniconda3\envs\gempy\lib\site-packages\pyvista\plotting\plotting.py", line 3425, in add_mesh
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Input mesh does not have texture coordinates to support the texture.

Any idea how to fix that ??

Do I need an update of pyVista to the newest version ? And if so, does gempy running with the newest version ?? Gempy / gemgis are very critical against package updates !! They are only working with Python 3.10.0.

Bests Christian

Tried to add a mesh with an rasterimage as texture to a pyvista plotter object.
I expected the mesh shown with the texture.

Comment: This was tracked in https://github.com/cgre-aachen/gemgis/issues/316 and has been resolved